# Calling (ID_number) primary key to textbox using Combobox (Category Description)

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

Dealing with Foreign Key using ms access in C#.

Each time I select the Category Description(CatDesc) using combobox from category table, I wanted to get/call automatically the Category Id(CatID) in the textbox1.

My code doesn't work, and no errors given.

This is my sample code:

```
private void cmdcategoryy_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       CategoryDesc();    
}

void CategoryDesc()

{
    OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\BlaBla\Desktop\Docsmonitorg\Try 081517\WindowsFormsApp6\WindowsFormsApp6\Database.accdb");

    string con;

    try
    {

        con = "Select CatID, CatDesc from Category where CatDesc = '" + cmdcategoryy.Text + "' ";
        mycon.Open();
        OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable mydata1 = new DataTable();

        cm.CommandText = con;
        cm.Connection = mycon;

        int i;
        da.SelectCommand = cm;
        da.Fill(mydata1);

        for (i = 0; i <= mydata1.Rows.Count - 1;)
            textBox1.Text = (mydata1.Rows[i]["CatID"].ToString());

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    }

    finally
    {
        mycon.Close();
        mycon.Dispose();
    }


}
```

[Here is the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpTKj.png)

[This is my Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZEWE.png)
Sample:

Category Description has Graphic Designer, AutoCat, AX Staff 
Category ID 1,2,3

I will hide that textbox1.

Comment: What is the content of your datatable `mydata1` if you debug it?

Comment: Is it sure that `CategoryDesc()` function event get called on event? Try calling this function from cmdcategoryy's ' `_SelectedIndexChanged` event rather than `_TextChanged`.

Comment: @M_Idrees yes I tried it but the result is same as _TextChanged.

Comment: You did not mentioned, if `CategoryDesc()` is getting called or not. Second as @mok suggested, you have to show the content of datatable `mydata1`.

Comment: Did you debug the code and check what value of `cmdcategoryy.Text` is being passed to the query? Did you check if table's row count is not zero?